# Ternary operation in asp.net in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Am trying to add an 'odd' class to a table row in a repeater control..

```
    <tr class="<%# If((Container.ItemIndex % 2 == 0), "even", "odd") %>">
```

I have verified that Container.ItemIndex returns the index number.

This causes it to throw this error..
First operand in a binary 'If' expression must be nullable or a reference type.

I also tried replacing the % with Mod keyword but it throws an "Expression expected" error..

Am new to coding asp.net in vb, tried searching for a solution but failed to get a working solution..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you should use only = instead of == and use mod

Comment: this happens when you used to different coding. you always look at it and it seems correct

Comment: Exactly lol, i dont think i would have had looked at the == to see if it was right because i was sure there would not be any problem with it.. am more used to C#

Answer (score 1):

To add to Amritpal answer, you should use `Mod` not `%`.

Comment: @AmritpalSingh sorry I didn't spot that.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<tr class="<%# If((Container.ItemIndex Mod 2 = 0), "even", "odd") %>">
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also try this :

```
 <tr class='<%# ((Container.ItemIndex % 2 == 0) ? "odd": "even") %>' >
```

Hops its helps

Answer (score 0):

If your target audience have browsers that implement the right CSS3 features, you can also accomplish this task purely with CSS:

http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/evenodd.en.html

Comment: I know, but i had a requirement of supporting older browser, thanks.